# My eyes get tired when I use Ubuntu, but not when I use Windows?

Tags: screen, brightness

This is a weird question, but it's one of the few reasons I haven't entirely switched to Linux yet. I have a ZenBook UX305 with Ubuntu Gnome and Windows 10 dual boot. For some reason, when I use Ubuntu my eyes get tired fairly quickly and I tend to get headaches every now and then, while using Windows never causes such problems. It happens especially on lighter screens, when I use Chrome for example. Also, when I bring down the brightness, it doesn't feel as comfortable as when I bring it down under Windows. I don't know how to put it more specifically... I'm not sure whether it has something to do with color calibration or something else, that's why I'm asking here.

EDIT: Output from running `xrandr`:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 
32767 x 32767 eDP1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 
(normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 293mm x 165mm

   1920x1080     60.05*+  59.93  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1368x768      60.00  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   1024x576      60.00  
   960x540       60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   864x486       60.00  
   640x480       59.94  
   720x405       60.00  
   640x360       60.00  
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Comment: Only thing I can imagine is that the refresh rate is not optimal. Could you [edit] and add the output of `xrandr`?

Comment: While refresh rate is mostly irrelevant on LCD screens, _resolution_ is _very_ relevant. Is your monitor set to its native resolution? If not, please set it to its native resolution. Are your fonts big enough?

Comment: It's running in a native resolution of 1920x1080. Because it's a 13" monitor I had to increase the font size, and it is big enough.

Comment: colour calibration is just for ensuring the on screen colours are reliably reproduced , this is important for designers who need to know the colours they choose are accurate, its mostly a non issue for others. It won't cause headaches.  What are your windows settings ?

Answer (score 0):

You're asking a pretty broad question so you're going to receive an equally broad answer. If you want to know details notify me with a comment and I can extend that part or look up further resources.

We can rule out screen resolution and the vertical screen frequency as possible causes because they're fine (for an LCD anyway).

### Font rendering

One thing known to be able to cause eye strain and typically differ between operating systems on the same hardware is font rendering (Linux, Windows, and OS X all have very different font renderers). That includes 1) **font face**, 2) **font size** and 3) **anti-aliasing** to make the font look smooth on a screen with a pixel size far above the wave length of visible light.

I recommend that you play around with those parameters until you find something suitable. In my experience one can notice different levels of eye strain quite quickly between different settings if you look at them for about 10 seconds each and focus on how your eye muscles feel.

I'll explain some details about the three different parameters mentioned before:

1. **font size:** bigger is better in terms of strain (up to a certain point) especially if your vision isn't perfect; on the other hand you'll want to fit as much content on your screen as possible, so you'll have to find a suitable balance.
2. **font face:** some are more legible on a particular medium (CRT, LCD, paper, etc.) than others; this may depend on the font size and anti-aliasing type. Don't assume that a font face that looks comfortable with one font renderer looks looks as comfortable with a different font renderer (e. g. on a different operating system)! Most fonts are optimised to look best with a particular font renderer on a particular medium.

   On Linux you should look for open-source fonts, e. g. those that are distributed through your package manager, since those are typically optimised for FreeType, the most common font renderer on Linux. Mozilla's and Google's fonts are optimised for FreeType as well. Many fonts distributed with Windows have open-source clones that are optimised for FreeType and included in Canonical's package repositories.
3. **anti-aliasing**: depends on the medium (here: screen) type; for LCDs it also depends on the screen orientation because it depends on the relative positions of red, green, and blue sub-pixels within a single three-colour pixel. Ubuntu can determine the right setting itself based on the information provided by the screen but you can force a different setting if you're screen doesn't provide one.

   You can also adjust the intensity of the anti-aliasing; on FreeType available settings are "simple/slight", "medium/moderate" and "maximal/strong". This will typically influence how thick and sharp the font lines appear. Stronger anti-aliasing will produce sharper looking font glyphs (less strenuous to read) with narrower lines (more strenuous to read), so you'll have to balance that too.

You can adjust all these settings with [Ubuntu Tweak](https://launchpad.net/~tualatrix/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) (Unity & Gnome), [Gnome Tweak Tool](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gnome-tweak-tool/) (Gnome only) or through the Dconf settings interface.